# Cannot open package explorer

Tags: eclipse

I'm not sure what I did, but somehow while committing code for a homework assignment I managed to close eclipse's package explorer, but I can't get it to open again. I went to window > show view  and clicked on package explorer, but it still did not show up.

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?Getting any errors?

Comment: It's Kepler eclipse. I wasn't getting anything, package explorer just wasn't showing up. I ended up resetting the perspective which fixed the problem.